# understanding c++ move_constructible concept implementation

Tags: c++, c++20, move-semantics, c++-concepts, move-constructor

I've got the following implementation of the c++ concept `move_constructible` from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/move_constructible)

```
template<typename _Tp>
concept move_constructible =
    constructible_from<_Tp, _Tp> &&
    convertible_to<_Tp, _Tp>;
```

I don't get why this works. I presume any type can be converted to itself, so the second requirement is pointless (God, I must be very wrong about something). Also, for the first requirement I would have expected something like `constructible_from<_Tp, _Tp&&>` to check if the type can be constructed from rvalue-ref (thus, moved).

Please explain how this implementation works.

Comment: On top of the selected answer, I want to add that it’s not true that any type can be converted to itself. Any type can be converted to a reference to itself, but T to T conversion requires a copy (implemented via copy or move construction), with actual copy/move ellided from the final code (feature called “copy ellision”).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most traits/concepts automatically add `&&` to the types of "source" arguments (things that are passed to functions, as in `std::is_invocable`, or constructed from, as in `std::is_constructible`).

I.e. `constructible_from<A, B>` is equivalent to `constructible_from<A, B &&>` (`&&` is automatically added to the second argument, but not to the first), and `convertible_to<A, B>` is equivalent to `convertible_to<A &&, B>`.

Note that if a type already includes `&`, adding `&&` to it has no effect. So, while `T` and `T &&` are equivalent here, `T &` is not.

---

This can be inferred from those traits/concepts being defined in terms of `std::declval<T>()`, which returns `T &&`.

For the reason why `std::declval<T &>()` returns `T &`, see [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

---

**NOTE:** There is one exception: passing an incomplete type (such as a class that was declared but not defined) as a non-first argument to `is_constructible` (and `constructible_from`) is UB, and some compilers reject it. Appending `&&` manually works around this rule, so in generic code, you should always prefer passing `T &&` to those traits.

But specifically for `move_constructible` there's no difference, since it makes no sense for incomplete types in the first place.

Comment: Why are both `convertible_to` and `constructible_from` needed?

Comment: @AlexGuteniev I'm not sure. `constructible_from` looks redundant, but maybe it somehow improves concept subsumption.

Comment: To forbidden non-implicit move constructor like `explicit A(A&&) = default;`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I think `convertible_to` alone would be enough for that, since it seems to check both implicit and explicit conversions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be strange if *only* `convertible_to` was used to build`move_constructible`? `constructible_from` is a necessary semantic requirement.

Comment: Reading the references, it seems there are some little differences between `convertible_to` and `constructible_from`. For example, `constructible_from` requires the type to be an object or reference type. I presume `convertible_to` works for other types of expressions.

Comment: Does `constructible_from` really add `&&` internally? In libstdc++ [I don't think it does](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/concepts#L152-L153). I guess that's because a *move-constructible* type can be initialized using its copy constructor unless its move constructor is explicitly deleted. I can only find [`is_move_constructible`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/type_traits#L3256) which adds `&&`.

Comment: @DeanSeo It forward to `is_constructible_v`, which should in turn add `&&`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [I don't think it does](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/type_traits#L1038-L1050) and that's okay, no? Because *move_constructible* is distinct to *move-only*.

Comment: @DeanSeo What am I supposed to see there? If we don't see `&&` being added in then library code, then it's implicitly added in the `__is_constructible` builtin. It's easy to check: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5625df8f4cea973c *"move-constructible type can be initialized using its copy constructor"* It's implicitly deleted if a move constructor is present. While all (sane) copyable types are movable, the opposite isn't true, and many movable types are not copyable (e.g. `unique_ptr`). *"move_constructible is distinct to move-only."* Yes, and?

Comment: @DeanSeo Cppreference says that [`std::constructible_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/constructible_from) calls [`std::is_constructible_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible), which in turn checks whether `T obj(std::declval<Args>()...);` compiles, and [`std::declval<T>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) returns `T &&`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Great, thanks. The builtin `__is_constructible` would do then add `&&` indeed. For some corner cases, the builtin function by the compiler seems essential as [the implementation of `std::is_constructible` is *tricky* and can't be portable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70836853/921070).