# C++20: Implement std::is_constructible using concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

Is there a portable way to implement `std::is_constructible` using concepts without `STL` using `requires` expression or template metaprogramming only?

Consider this code:

```cpp
template <class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible
    : std::bool_constant<requires {
      new T(std::declval<Args>()...);
    }> {
};
```

It works fine for other data types except for references because one can't `new` a reference type.

```cpp
// Test cases
auto main() -> int {
  static_assert(is_constructible<int>::value);
  static_assert(is_constructible<int, int>::value);
  static_assert(is_constructible<int, float>::value);
  static_assert(!is_constructible<int, int *>::value);
  static_assert(is_constructible<int &, int &>::value);
  static_assert(is_constructible<int &&, int &&>::value);
  static_assert(!is_constructible<void, void>::value);
  static_assert(!is_constructible<int(), int()>::value);
  static_assert(is_constructible<int (*)(), int()>::value);
  static_assert(!is_constructible<intptr_t, int *>::value);
  static_assert(!is_constructible<int &, float &>::value);

  static_assert(std::is_constructible<int>::value);
  static_assert(std::is_constructible<int, int>::value);
  static_assert(std::is_constructible<int, float>::value);
  static_assert(!std::is_constructible<int, int *>::value);
  static_assert(std::is_constructible<int &, int &>::value);
  static_assert(std::is_constructible<int &&, int &&>::value);
  static_assert(!std::is_constructible<void, void>::value);
  static_assert(!std::is_constructible<int(), int()>::value);
  static_assert(std::is_constructible<int (*)(), int()>::value);
  static_assert(!std::is_constructible<intptr_t, int *>::value);
  static_assert(!std::is_constructible<int &, float &>::value);
  
  return {};
}
```

Comment: There's already a standard library concept for this [`std::default_initializable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/default_initializable). It's just a different name then the type trait. EDIT: wait! I think you're looking for [`std::constructible_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/constructible_from).

Comment: I don't think the approach using `new` is sufficient. A standard-conform `std::is_constructible` should check that an imagined declaration `T obj(declval<Args>()...);` is well-formed. That should include a check for usability of the destructor which `new` doesn't require.

Comment: I know brother, I know. I have to implement it as a practice question.

Comment: ?? Just copy the cpp reference code then??

Comment: [lol](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/028/986/scropio.jpg) The implementation uses `std::constructible_from` which in turn uses `std::is_constructible` which does not provide any implementation. @JHBonarius

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Certainly not "cleanly and nicely".

In fact, early proposals during the standardization process attempted to implement `constructible_from` using `requires` expressions, but there were so many corner cases that we gave up and specified it in terms of the type trait instead.

Comment: So, how can we implement the type trait? As far as I know libc++ uses `__is_constructible` in its implementation.

Comment: @MansoorAhmedMemon It may not be possible or possible in an efficient manner to implement `std::is_constructible` without a compiler built-in, which is probably why the standard library implementations use one.

Comment: Thanks! Is `__is_constructible` portable tho?

Comment: "Is __is_constructible portable" No.

Comment: @MansoorAhmedMemon The standard library is poorly named.  It is not a library in a normal sense; it isn't on top of language features.  It is an interface to language features, some of which are implemented (partly or mostly) in-language.

Comment: @user17732522 "*It may not be possible or possible in an efficient manner to implement std::is_constructible without a compiler built-in*" I'm intrigued to ask why though, where would I get to read the discussions (if any)?

Comment: @DeanSeo I am not saying that it is definitively impossible, just that this is a possibility. But even if it is possible then, as this answer is saying, there will be so many corner cases to consider that implementation without intrinsic will become infeasible or at least too cumbersome. See also for example the answer and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439909/c98-03-stdis-constructible-implementation).